# Удаленное подключение к базе данных MySQL

Tags: c#

Привет. В общем, необходимо удаленно подключиться к базе данных.

Сделал вот такой код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=xxxx;user=xxxx;database=xxxx;password=xxxx;"))
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Подключился");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Вместо **xxxx**, конечно, стоят мои данные.

Так вот, выходит вот такая вот ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**НО**, если к данным подключения добавить port, то ошибки нет, но и диалоговое окно не показывает что подключение установлено и к тому же, приложение просто зависает.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? На VPS галочка "удаленный доступ" стоит и прописан тот же IP что и в коде.

Comment: Возможно вместо user=xxxx; нужно написать UID как в примере по ссылке ниже.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618015/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database
И у вас не указано к какой БД подключаться, именно название БД

Comment: @Atlantis, UID - не помогло. Разве нужно указывать какой БД ИМЕННО подключаться? Как указать? Просто ни разу такое не видел. Обычно же просто название базы вроде..

Comment: пробовали к локальному серверу так подключиться? MySQL не слишком тяжелый и тренироваться лучше на кошках. Если с локальным все успешно, то нужно искать проблему за пределами вашего кода

Comment: @rdorn, да, локально всё работает прекрасно. Тех.поддержка тоже говорит, мол что настроено всё правильно, возможно проблема в скрипте.

Comment: чем нибудь типа MySQL Workbanch  или любым другим клиентом подключиться получается?

Comment: @rdorn, пробовал через HeidiSQL, тоже самое – локальное подключение работает, удаленное нет.

Comment: ну тогда это вопрос в ТП хостера, где сервер размещен. Тут помочь нечем

Comment: @rdorn, не подскажите где можно хранить базу данных бесплатно? Ну или хотя бы для теста, чтобы проверить.

Comment: для теста - на соседнем компе связанном по сети. И проверьте еще что в настройках самого MySQL разрешены внешние подключения, по умолчанию это запрещено.

Comment: @rdorn, можно по подробнее про внешние подключения? В настройках пользователя БД стоит галочка удаленный доступ и IP прописан.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37222/discussion-between-rdorn-and-).